# How to implement an Asynchronous TCP Client

Tags: c#, xml, asynchronous, tcp, tcpclient

**Following Situation:**
I communicate remotely to a device with TCP/IP. I send a command to device. The device executes the command and sends me `asynchronously` the result messages. The time between the messages can vary in a wide range. I don't want a blocking function that waits till all messages are received. So I am working with `callback functions`, so the function is only called when a message is received.
In the next step I append these received messages to a string value. In the background I want to `process the messages` one by one and remove the processed message from the string value.
**Now my questions:**
1. I an new, so I firstly want to aks experienced people about the implementation.
2. Where is the best occasion to process the response messages?
3. Do I have to use a Mutex, because there could be the case that I write and read the response?

**Responses**
There are two different types of responses: Standard Responses and Notifications. While processing the messages I've to distinguish these types.
The XML response messages correspond as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Telegram xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xmlns="LancePlatform">
    Response or Notification
</Telegram>
```

FYI: 
The XML responses always starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8 standalone="yes" ?>
```

and ends by a sequence of CR+LF

**My Code:**

```
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.  
    public TcpClient workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 4096;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class Client
{
    private StateObject state;
    private String response { get; set; }

    public void Connect(string host, Int32 port)
    {
        try
        {
            client = new StateObject();
            client.workSocket = new TcpClient(host, port);
        }
        // SocketException
    }

    public void BeginRead()
    {
        NetworkStream ns = state.workSocket.GetStream();
        ns.BeginRead(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, EndRead, state);
    }

    private void EndRead(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            state  = (StateObject)AR.AsyncState;

            NetworkStream ns = state.workSocket.GetStream();

            // Get the number of received bytes
            int receivedBytes = ns.EndRead(AR);

            // Append the message to the string value.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, receivedBytes));

            // Get the number of remaining bytes.
            int remainingBytes = state.workSocket.Available;

            // More data available
            if (remainingBytes != 0)
            {
                ns.BeginRead(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, EndRead, state);
            } else 
            {
                // Should I process the messages here or somewhere else, 
                // so I don't block this function with processing messages?
                ProcessMessages();
            }
        }
        // SocketException
    }

    public void ProcessMessages()
    {
        // Split the message by CR+LF. Because each message ends with that.
        string[] messages = Regex.Split(response, "\r\n");
        foreach (string message in messages)
        {
            // Deserialize XML String to Object.
            // Remove message string from response string.
        }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // ...
        Client client = new Client();
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        client.BeginRead();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: See msdn examples.  Example uses Socket but you can replace socket with any class the inherits the socket like TCPClient or TCPListener : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: I am not sure if that's possible, becaause the `TcpClient` for example doesn't have the methods `Receive`, `ReceiveCallback`, `Send`,... 
which are used in the example you sent.

Comment: Yes it does.  The socket properties are under Client property.

Comment: You're right! Thanks! And what about the 2 other questions? Do you've any suggestion?

Comment: Most programmer do not know anything about the 7 Network Layers (including the Microsoft examples).  So most software you will see doing the response in the Async Receive method which is the transport layer which is the easy solution.  The correct method is to Send and process the response at the application layer.  So what I like to do is use a State object and in the receive method write the receive data into the state object.  Then have application layer read the data from the state object.

Comment: Question 3.  It depends on the application protocol.  The device may be in a continuous transmit mode or you are implementing a master/slave communication application.  The client is the master and the server is the slave.  So normally you client would send commands and server would respond to commands.  You try to avoid the server sending messages without a client requesting a response.

Comment: Okay, so I will process the messages in the application layer.

Comment: Comment about Question 3: The problem is, that with 1 command, I get multiple responses..

Comment: Normally when you get multiple response the first is just an ack that server got command and then 2nd is when command is finished.  Every message must have a known end of message either by size or a terminating character.  So multiple responses will occur on long messages and client wait until end of message.

Comment: But in my case, it's like this: With a command I start a measurement. The device gives me the first answer, which is just a acknowledgement that the measurement has started.
Then I get 3 response messages, with the result values. As I said before, the time between these answers can vary over a wide range. At the end I get a message that the measurement is finished. 
And I don't want to wait to read the messages until the measurement is done.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing other work, but you can't send another command until you get the entire response (all three parts).  You may be able to process each response independently.  But all this should be done at the application layer and not in the Async Read.  The Async Read should be exited as quickly as possible.  The BeginRead enables the next Read to occur and you may miss data (or data will get queue up).  The max amount of data that code can handle is BufferSize = 4096.  So code either has to keep up or you have to create another buffer.

Comment: Okay! I think I got it! Then may I ask you a next question:
When processing messages in the application layer, how can I indicate that new responses are stored in the variable? Because a blocking while loop to check for new messages is not the right solution.
I assume that I need to send a signal when new messages are received, or that I need to notify when there are changes to the variable.

Comment: Looks at the MSDN Async Server example which use WaitHandler to signal when messages are received : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: @jdweng What do you think about the new Implementation below?

Comment: How long is the connection going to be opened?  How many messages are you going to get while the connection is open?  You code is waiting until the connection is closed before reading the data since the read is in the EndRead.

Comment: Until everything's done. I establish a connection to the device. Then I send a status request. In the one answer I receive, I can read a value that indicates whether the device is ready for remote control. Then I send another request to set the device in remote mode. Again, I get an answer if the request was successful. Then I send a request to configure some settings. Again I get an answer if the settings could be done. 
Now I am ready to send the request to start the measurement. With this request I get multiple responses. It depends on the number of measurement points I have set up.

Comment: Most people leave connections open until done.  A lot of Microsoft examples closes connections after each message (I do not like this approach).  So with your code you are not processing the data until the connection is closed.

Comment: Why do you think? If I run the code I process the response message one after another.

Comment: Your read is in the EndRead event which only occurs when the connection is closed.

Comment: `ns.BeginRead(State.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, EndRead, State)`
I think the callback `EndRead` is called each time one `"package"` with the given buffer size is read out of the `Networkstream`

Comment: Isn't it? @jdweng

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right way to ask about my new implementation by answering my own question.

## The Approach is as follows:

- Connect with the Device

**First Request**

- Send Request
- Start Reading
- Process the Response or multiple Response

**Second Request**

- Send the next Request
- Start Reading
- Process the Responses or multiple Response

**My Code:**

```
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.  
    public TcpClient workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 4096;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

    public string responseMessage = "";
}

 public class Client
{
    private StateObject state;
    // Create a new Mutex. The Mutex is when we're writing ore reating the Data of the State Object.
    private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();

    public static ManualResetEvent MessageReceived = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public StateObject State { get => state; set => state = value; }

    private void EndRead(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            State = (StateObject)AR.AsyncState;

            NetworkStream ns = State.workSocket.GetStream();

            // Get the number of received bytes
            int receivedBytes = ns.EndRead(AR);

            // Connection Closed
            if (receivedBytes == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (receivedBytes > 0)
            {
                // Append buffer content to String.    
                mut.WaitOne();
                State.data.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(State.buffer, 0, receivedBytes));
                mut.ReleaseMutex();

                if(State.data.ToString().Contains(MettlerToledo.Message.END_DELIMITER))
                {
                    // Copy thread save the content into the Response Message.
                    mut.WaitOne();
                    State.responseMessage = State.data.ToString();
                    mut.ReleaseMutex();
                    // Send the signal we got the entire message. So the message can be processed.
                    MessageReceived.Set();
                } else
                {
                    // Message not yet complete, so we're waiting for more data.
                    ns.BeginRead(State.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, EndRead, state);
                }
            }
        }
        // Catch Exceptions
    }


    public void BeginRead()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Read");
        try
        {
            NetworkStream ns = State.workSocket.GetStream();
            ns.BeginRead(State.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, EndRead, State);

        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 62324);

        // F I R S T   R E Q U E S T   -    O N E   R E S P O N S E 
        // Send Request
        client.BeginSend(/* Some XML Request string*/);
        // Start Reading
        client.BeginRead();
        // Waiting for Response
        Client.MessageReceived.WaitOne();
        /* Process the responseMessage
         * ...
         */
        // Clear the Processed Data 
        client.State.data.Clear();
        Client.MessageReceived.Reset();

        // S E C O N D   R E Q U E S T   -   M U L T I P L E   R E S P O N S E S
        // Send Next Request 
        client.BeginSend(/* Some XML Request string*/);
        // Start Reading again
        client.BeginRead();
        // Waiting for 1. Response
        Client.MessageReceived.WaitOne();
        /* Process the next responseMessage
         * ...
         */
        // Clear the Processed Data 
        client.State.data.Clear();
        Client.MessageReceived.Reset();

        // Waiting for 2. Response
        client.BeginRead();
        Client.MessageReceived.WaitOne();
        /* Process the next responseMessage
         * ...
         */
        // Clear the Processed Data 
        client.State.data.Clear();
        Client.MessageReceived.Reset();


        // N E X T   R E Q U E S T S 
        // ....
    }
}
```